# proving homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

Is there a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^{2} $
  and the set  $ A=\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}:x^{2}+y^{2}<1\right\} $
  ?

And what if $A=\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}:x^{2}+y^{2}\leq1\right\} $?

At the second part I think there is no homeomorphism  since the closed ball is compact space and  $\mathbb{R}^{2} $ isn't. But Im not sure about my arguments. :S

Comment: The proof of the second part is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen that the interval $(0,1)$ is homeomorphic to the real line? If not, try to prove that. Once we know that, we know we can perform a continuous stretching of that interval into any line.

Imagine the open unit disk (the set A) drawn in the center of a cartesian plane. Fix the center, consider each of the rays out of the center of the circle as rotations of the interval (0,1). We can apply the same continuous stretching as before to each of these rays, and we end up with the entire plane. So that is a homeomorphism from the open unit disk to the plane.

Your reasoning for the second one is correct, but lets remind ourselves why. Homeomorphisms are functions which preserve the topology between two spaces: open sets in one correspond to open sets in the other. Suppose there was a homeomorphism between the plane and the closed unit disk. The plane is not compact, so there is some open cover with no finite subcover. Now take the images of all the sets in that cover. This would produce an open cover on the closed unit disk with no finite subcover, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

For the first set, try $(x,y)\mapsto \left( x\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+1},y\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+1}\right)$.

For the second part, your argument is correct.

Comment: This answer is correct, but of course the formula you gave is not very helpful - I mean sure, it is right, but how'd you get it? Surely you can shed some light on that.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. If we let $r$ be the length of the vector $(x,y)$ then this sends $(x,y)\mapsto \frac{r}{r+1}(x,y)$ which is basically radially shrinking the source. This barely moves points far away from the origin, and is not a mapping from the plane to the open unit disk or vice versa.

Comment: @KatieDobbs oops, I corrected the formula to $\frac1r(x,y)$. So for small $r$, this is nearly the identity, but the resulting point has distance $\frac r{r+1}$ (that's where I mixed up), which will always be $<1$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first try $f:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow A, \ \ f(x,y)=f(re^{i\theta})=\left(\dfrac{2}{e^r+1}-1\right)e^{i\theta}, \ r \in \mathbb{R}, \ \theta \in [0,\pi)$.
(The function $g:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow (-1,1), r\mapsto \left(\dfrac{2}{e^r+1}-1\right)$ is homeomorphism).

For the second you are right.

Comment: Actually, it is a homeomorphism of $[0,+\infty)$ and $[0,1)$, which is far more important, because you don't care about how it acts on $r$ negative. You could just as well have taken $\frac{x}{x+1}$, I think.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Correct it could be a lot easier in your way. But I think mine is correct as well because I choose different(from the normal) polar representation of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct, I was just making it clear that you don't need $g$ to be a homeomorphism between $\mathbb R$ and $(-1,1)$, and, in particular, you need $g(0)=0$, rather than an arbitrary homeomorphism $g$. On the other hand, any homeomorphism between $[0,\infty)$ and $[0,1)$ will do.